# Specifying Binding for Texture Arrays in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In glsl 420 functionality was added to specify binding in the shader instead of having to call `glUniform1i`. For example:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
```

But how can that be done for arrays?

```
layout(binding ?) uniform sampler2D u_Textures[16];
```

I want the bindings to be 0,1,2,...,15. Is there no way for me to do this in glsl without any `glUniform` calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.4.5. Uniform and Shader Storage Block Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#layout-qualifiers):

> When used with OpenGL, if the binding qualifier is used with a uniform block or shader storage block instanced as an array, **the first element of the array takes the specified block binding and each subsequent element takes the next consecutive binding point**.

That means you just have to specify the binding point of the first sampler in the array:

```py
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_Textures[16];
```

---

But note, when samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader, these types can only be indexed with a [dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression), or texture lookup will result in undefined values.

I recommend to use `sampler2DArray` (see [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))) rather than an array of `sampler2D`.

<sub>See also:

[Why are Uniform variables not working in GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290812/why-are-uniform-variables-not-working-in-glsl)

[In a fragment shader, why can't I use a flat input integer to index a uniform array of sampler2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388274/in-a-fragment-shader-why-cant-i-use-a-flat-input-integer-to-index-a-uniform-ar)</sub>